# ¿Como cargo una imagen sobre un botón, respetando las transparencias de la imagen .png?

Tags: python, tkinter, botón, interfaz-gráfica

[image: boton de la interfaz]

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
ox = root.winfo_screenwidth()/2
oy = root.winfo_screenheight()/2
root.geometry("=300x300+%d+%d" % (ox-400,oy-345) )                                                                              #sin bordes

miFrame=Frame(root, bg="grey32", width=800, height=670)
miFrame.pack()  

miImagen = PhotoImage(file="boton.png")
roundedbutton = Button(miFrame,image=miImagen, bg= "grey95",  fg= "white", border=0)
roundedbutton.place(x=60,y=100)
root.mainloop()
```

El problema es que deseo añadir este tipo de botones a traves de imagenes .png y PhotoImage, con bordes redondeados.. pero cuando cargo la imagen, la transparencia del .png se cambia a color blanco y "ensucia" la interfaz.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes revisar la documentación de Tkinter http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm
En ella se especifica la prpiedad Tkbutton.config
Donde puedes establecler el background color como None para que se quede transparente

O puedes revisar este link 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51889265/how-create-button-with-png-background-in-tkinter

Comment: Hola, esta propiedad no responde a mi necesidad. Se está reemplanzado la parte transparente de la imagen por color blanco.

Comment: @tho7o, tal vez esto te sirva https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51889265/how-create-button-with-png-background-in-tkinter

Comment: Gracias. No me sirve porque mi fondo no es unicolor.. ¿Tienes alguna otra idea?